# Trying to understand how to access dictionaries outside of object/script

Tags: dictionary, unity-game-engine

I don't think I understand dictionaries at all. I understand how to set them up and access them from the same script/object but when it comes to accessing it from a different object/script that's not parent/child I have no idea what I'm doing. This is my script for the gameobject holding the dictionaries:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class HeroStats : MonoBehaviour {

    //Dictionary Structure <Key, value>

    Dictionary<string,int> HeroStat = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    Dictionary<string,string>HeroName = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    Dictionary<string,string>StatDef = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    //Initialization:
    void Start(){
    //===NAME==========================
    HeroName.Add("Name","Insert Name");
    //===STATS=========================
    HeroStat.Add("Constitution", 3);
    HeroStat.Add("Dexterity", 3);
    HeroStat.Add("Intelligence", 3);
    HeroStat.Add("Strength", 3);
    HeroStat.Add("Wisdom", 3);
    //===STAT DEFINITION==============
    StatDef.Add("Constitution", "Your Overall Healthiness");

        print (HeroName["Name"]);
        print (HeroStat["Strength"]);
    }
}
```

and this is the script I'm trying to use to access the dictionary:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class heroName : MonoBehaviour {

    public HeroStats heroStats;
    public Text text;
    public string lookUp;
    public string what;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start(){
        heroStats = FindObjectOfType<HeroStats>();
        what = heroStats.GetType().GetField("Name").GetValue(this).ToString();
        text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        lookUp = this.gameObject.name;
    }

    void Update(){
    }
}
```

I just have no idea what I'm doing at this point or know what to google. Every video/tutorial I've seen always shows them accessing the dictionary from the same script/object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Dictionary is just a way of storing data. Just like an int, or string. You need to have access to your Dictionary in your external script.

You would need to make your Dictionary public in HeroStats, and then in heroName you would simply have

```
heroStats.HeroStat["Constitution"]
```

Comment: Oh my god... I completely missed the public. Wow I've been reading about dictionaries for the last 3 or so hours (it's 5 AM) and I never though to put public infront of my dictionaries... Thank you Atra so much... holy wow... I should go to sleep

Comment: I know this is answered but I want to add something important to it. It it not a good idea to make your the Dictionary public. The best way to do this is to make a public function that can update or access the dictionary. For example, public updateHetro( string Value){
heroStats.HeroStat[Value];
}